# Tie System.map values to kernel addresses

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux

I'm trying to boot a custom kernel on a BeagleBoneBlack. u-boot works, and loads stuff as follows:

```
U-Boot 2016.03 (Apr 26 2016 - 11:32:30 +0000)

       Watchdog enabled
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  512 MiB
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

Net:   <ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
cpsw, usb_ether
Press SPACE to abort autoboot in 2 seconds
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
Found /boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf
Retrieving file: /boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf
278 bytes read in 39 ms (6.8 KiB/s)
1:      Linux grsec
Retrieving file: /boot/initramfs-grsec
5875398 bytes read in 349 ms (16.1 MiB/s)
Retrieving file: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.8-grsec
3140944 bytes read in 211 ms (14.2 MiB/s)
append: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.8-grsec modules=loop,squashfs,sd-mod,usb-storage modloop=/boot/modloop-grsec console=ttyO0,115200n8
Retrieving file: /boot/dtbs/am335x-boneblack.dtb
31516 bytes read in 426 ms (71.3 KiB/s)
Kernel image @ 0x82000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x2fed50 ]
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 88000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x88000000
   Loading Ramdisk to 8fa65000, end 8ffff6c6 ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 8fa5a000, end 8fa64b1b ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

Everything looks good so far, I think. But the kernel fails to load. I can't get access to anything from the kernel with low level debugging enabled in the kernel options either.

I've attached a J-Link JTAG debugger and was hoping to trace through to the problem, but I'm having trouble tying the System.map through to the disassembly.

Here for example is the start of the System.Map:

```
00000000 t __vectors_start
00000024 A cpu_ca8_suspend_size
00000024 A cpu_v7_suspend_size
0000002c A cpu_ca9mp_suspend_size
00001000 t __stubs_start
00001004 t vector_rst
00001020 t vector_irq
000010a0 t vector_dabt
00001120 t vector_pabt
000011a0 t vector_und
00001220 t vector_addrexcptn
00001240 t vector_fiq
00001240 T vector_fiq_offset
80204000 A swapper_pg_dir
80208000 T _text
80208000 T stext
8020808c t __create_page_tables
8020813c t __turn_mmu_on_loc
80208148 t __fixup_smp
802081b0 t __fixup_smp_on_up
802081d4 t __fixup_pv_table
80208228 t __vet_atags
80208280 T __idmap_text_start
80208280 T __turn_mmu_on
80208280 T _stext
```

So taking __create_page_tables, I grep in the source code under ./arch/arm/kernel with:

```
.../arm/arm/kernel$ grep __create_page_tables -rn
Binary file head.o matches
head.S:128:     bl      __create_page_tables
head.S:180:__create_page_tables:
head.S:355:ENDPROC(__create_page_tables)
```

So we're looking for the following at the symbol address:

```
__create_page_tables:
    pgtbl   r4, r8                          @ page table address
```

But the disassembler shows something different at the address I'm translating too give the Kernel is loaded at 0x82000000:

[image: Kernel __create_page_tables address]

How can I translate the kernel symbols to the debugger addresses?

Comment: Have you enabled early printk?

Comment: Hi Alex, no I haven't. But things don't get that far I'm afraid. The processor thows an exception at 82002E8C. The MRC co-processor instruction shown here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BrianSidebotham/alpine-on-bbb/master/linux-grsec/linux-4.4.8-grsec-offending-instruction.png

Comment: I should note that building this kernel without the generic armhf Alipine Linux config and instead using omap2plus_defconfig with grsec (it's a grsec patched 4.4.8 kernel) lets the kernel boot okay. I could do with tying the symbols back to the source so I can track down the offending option in the kernel config.

Comment: Hi Brian, so ok, you are right about early printk. Two things appears in mind: 1. objdump -d ./vmlinux, but that looks like the same thing you have tried with System.map. It should match what you see in debugger if you didn't mess up something with load addr or vmlinux version (worth to try). 2. You can implement your own assembly printk for debug reasons. For that you only need to know the bese address of UART from dtb.Uboot had initialized UART before kernel so no prilimenary init states are needed. Just writing a byte to appropriate port should work. So this shouldn't be complicated.

Comment: I am not in expert in ARM but what is P4? And the instruction code looks strange EF123456, is this a real instruction?

Comment: It looks a lot like you're crashing in the zImage decompressor - that "disassembly" is definitely not code, and 32KB past the initial load address is well past the decompressor stub and into the compressed data, which would look about as random as those bytes. In other words, at this point the vmlinux symbols are irrelevant, because you're still deep in the arch/arm/boot/compressed/ voodoo.

Comment: OK, it doesn't answer the question asked, but after a bit of digging, I can say that that config apparently has low-level debugging via semihosting enabled (and you are consequently crashing on an unhandled semihosting `putc` call, probably just trying to print the "Decompressing the kernel" message), and also that your disassembler is broken, because it thinks an `svc` is an `mrc`...